# Is there any diference between using ref callback as inline function or as a stable function with useCallback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which take a children as props and render it inside a div which has a callback ref.

```
const ShowMoreText = (props: ShowLessOrMoreProps) => {
  const { children } = props;

  const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [showButton, setShowButton] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [childrenHeight, setChildrenHeight] = useState<number>(9.5);

  const measureRef = useCallback((node: HTMLDivElement) => {
    if (node) {
     setChildrenHeight(node.getBoundingClientRect().height);
   }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
   console.log(childrenHeight)// when use measureRef function it gives me 0 when using inline version this gives me correct height and I don't know why
   if (childrenHeight > 45) {
      setShowButton(true);
    }
  }, [childrenHeight]);

  return (
    <Stack
      sx={{
        alignItems: "flex-start",
      }}
    >
      <Collapse in={showMore} collapsedSize={45}>
        <div
          // ref={(node: HTMLDivElement) => {
          //   setChildrenHeight(node?.getBoundingClientRect().height);
          // }}
          ref={() => measureRef} // if I comment this and use the above commmented version everything works fine
        >
          {children}
        </div>
      </Collapse>
      {showButton && ( //when using measureRef function this button won't display
        <Button onClick={() => setShowMore((prev) => !prev)}>
          {showMore ? "Show less" : "Show more"}
        </Button>
      )}
    </Stack>
  );
};
```

the problem is that when I use stable measureRef function the console log inside useeffect prints 0 but in inline ref version everythings works fine. can anyone explain me why ?

Comment: No point in using `useCallback` here

Comment: You really should use `useRef` and `useLayoutEffect` for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and share it here in case anyone is curious or have a same problem.
The problem was that the children that I passed to this component was something like this:

```
<ShowMoreText>
   <div>{result?.items[0]?.snippet?.description}</div>
</ShowMoreText>
```

and because of the delay of request the div height was actually 0 at the beginning. so the actual code for callback ref worked correct and the problem raised because of the api call delay. the solution for me and the mistake that i had been made was not to render the above code conditionally like this:

```
{dataIsLoading && 
     <ShowMoreText>
         <div>{result?.items[0]?.snippet?.description}</div>
     </ShowMoreText>
}
```

hopefully this can help someone else.

Comment: Probably you should just add `children` to the dependency array of `useEffect` so that it checks the height whenever the rendered content changes.

Comment: Seems obvious and reasonable. thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
ref={(node: HTMLDivElement) => {
          //   setChildrenHeight(node?.getBoundingClientRect().height);
          // }}
```

You return a function but ref shoulb be an Object (of certain type)
Hence You probably return void function.
if You want to pass `(node: HTMLDivElement) => {          //   setChildrenHeight(node?.getBoundingClientRect().height);          // }`  use unreserved prop then.
**props.ref** is reserved for useRef() hook .

Finally :
If for some reason Yuu want to save such contruction, do thi that way:

```
(node: HTMLDivElement) => {
   return setChildrenHeight(node?.getBoundingClientRect().height);
          }}
```

Where setChildrenHeight() returns correct object type proper po ref.

Comment: But the problem ia that when I use callback ref even this way it works. But when i comment this inline ref and use measure function it always gives me 0 as the childrenHeight

Comment: It's bocouse Your callback returns [], which is acceptable as ref value.

Comment: Got it. And any possibility to guess why using function doesn't work at all and always gives me 0 as the height ?

Comment: Becouse function returns nothing until it not reaches a return statement (if present)
OOP describes 2 kind of functions essentially functions as returning values ( with "return [some calue/function]" statement ), and void  ( without  return statement) .
You would have to include return at least in highest function in that function tree.
()={return ()=>{return "ssss"}}  will return "sss", but ()=>{ ()=>{} } will return undefined. 
hence function x(){};   ()=>{ ()=>{return x;} } will return reference to function x and ()=>{ ()=>{return x;} }() will call function x();

Comment: Thank you for your response. I checked but actually the problem was something else that I shared as a response.